# How to pass an additional argument to jQuery filter function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a for-loop to filter some tables:

```
for(columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= contentColumnsNumber; columnIndex++) {
  $clonedTable = $table.clone();

  $clonedTable.find('th, td').filter(function() {
    if($(this).index() === 0 || $(this).index() === columnIndex) {
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }).remove();

  $clonedTable.appendTo($mobileTablesWrap);
}
```

JSLint recommends not to create functions within a loop:
http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-loop-func

Because of that, I want to refactor this code. So I've created another method and call those, instead of the inline function:

```
function getRemovableCells(index, element, columnIndex) {
  if($(this).index() === 0 || $(this).index() === columnIndex) {
    return false;
  }

  return true;
}

function filterTable() {
  [...]

  for(columnIndex = 1; columnIndex <= contentColumnsNumber; columnIndex++) {
    $clonedTable = $table.clone();

    $clonedTable.find('th, td').filter(getRemovableCells).remove();

    $clonedTable.appendTo($mobileTablesWrap);
  }
}
```

Now, my problem is to get the value of `columnIndex`. This value is provided by the loop and I need to pass them to the filter function. The filter function got already two arguments named `index` and `element`:
http://api.jquery.com/filter/#filter-function

So I've tried to pass the variable in the loop but then, the context will be altered. I'm just overwriting the existing arguments and `this`.

```
$clonedTable.find('th, td').filter(getRemovableCells(columnIndex)).remove();
```

Also `bind` or `call` / `apply` doesn't helps me out.

Comment: For what its worth, I don't see anything wrong with your first code sample, despite what JSLint says. jQuery throws anonymous functions around for fun, it's not a problem.

Comment: Technically you are putting more strain on the browser but defining functions over and over in a loop, though you do put more strain on the memory by naming a function to keep at all times... its an iffy decision.

Comment: The problem with some of the jslint rules is that they are there incase you make a potential error - if you don't make that error (because you *actually* know what you're doing...), then there's no problem.  In this case, you are not calling the function outside the loop, so no problem.

Comment: Yeah, it is not that big issue. But nonetheless I think, that it is more cleaner to move the function out of the for-loop. So the code is more readable...

Comment: Readability is in the eye of the reader - the first code is *much* more readable to me and will be like this in all the jquery documentation and examples.

Comment: Alright, but when you follow the _clean code principle_, it is more readable when you have a function named `getRemovableCells`. Therefore you can easily understand what this piece of code does. You don't actually have to look into the function itself and read the details. The name of the function is also the documentation. So it is easy understandable for skilled and unskilled readers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) for this:

```
function getRemovableCells(columnIndex) {
  return function(index, element) {
    if($(this).index() === 0 || $(this).index() === columnIndex) {
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the solution and the answer to the question, though I would recommend just ignoring the JSLint and going with anonymous function in this case...